# May 20th Annular Eclipse - Duration from Vancouver?

Tags: astronomy

On May 20th, [there's an annular eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_eclipse_of_May_20,_2012).

It's technically visible towards the end from Vancouver.  In the middle, the duration is just under 6 minutes.  What I want to know is what the duration is expected to be for a viewer located in Vancouver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NASA has a wonderful web page set up that gives you great maps and information on each individual eclipse.  The one you are asking about is located at http://eclipse.gsfc.nasa.gov/OH/OH2012.html#SE2012May20A.  In terms of a description, this is probably the part you are interested in:

> The shadow passes just south of Alaska's Aleutian Islands as the central track slowly curves to the southeast. After a 7000 kilometre-long ocean voyage lasting nearly 2 hours, the antumbra finally reaches land again along the rugged coastlines of southern Oregon and northern California (Figure 2) at 01:23 UT (May 20 local time).
>
> Redding, CA lies 30 kilometres south of the central line. Nevertheless, it still experiences an annular phase lasting 4 1/2 minutes beginning at 01:26 UT. It is already late afternoon along this section of the eclipse path. The Sun's altitude is 20° during the annular phase and decreasing as the track heads southeast. Central Nevada, southern Utah, and northern Arizona are all within the annular path.
>
> By the time the antumbra reaches Albuquerque, NM (01:34 UT), the central duration is still 4 1/2 minutes, but the Sun's altitude has dropped to 5°. As its leading edge reaches the Texas Panhandle, the shadow is now an elongated ellipse extending all the way to Nevada. Seconds later, the antumbra begins its rise back into space above western Texas as the track and the annular eclipse end.

The main page is at this URL:  http://eclipse.gsfc.nasa.gov/eclipse.html  I know I am using it to plan my [2017](http://eclipse.gsfc.nasa.gov/SEplot/SEplot2001/SE2017Aug21T.GIF) trip to Kentucky.  :)

As for your specific location, [here is a web page](http://astro.ukho.gov.uk/eclipse/0132012/) that gives you a picture and animation for [your specific location](http://astro.ukho.gov.uk/eclipse/Vancouver_B_C_Canada.html).

[image: Eclipse in Vancouver]

[image: Eclipse animation]